# How to update home screen based on user authentication state with Firebase in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to update the `MyApp(home:)` screen in my flutter app whenever I call the `logOut()`function and log out the user.
Currently I set a StreamBuilder to listen to all the authStateChanges, and it works when starting the app, but when I am running the app and log out the user, the screen doesn't update.
This is my code:

```
class StartupLogic {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    Widget getLandingPage() {
        return StreamBuilder<User>(
            stream: _auth.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return HomePageScreen();
              }
    
              return WelcomeScreen();
            });
      } 
    }
```

And in the main.dart file I have:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  ...

  home: StartupLogic().getLandingPage(),
```

This is working the first time I start the app, redirecting the user to the `WelcomeScreen()` if not logged in, but when I am logged in and then I logout, the screen doesn't automatically change.
How can I trigger the `home:` parameter when running the app?

Comment: The `authStateChanges` will be triggered for any auth state changes (including signing out) as long as it's active. Are you sure your `StartupLogic` class is still active when you sign out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

You need to pass the `context` of `MyApp` in the main.dart file as an argument to the `StreamBuilder` to make it work.
My updated code:

```
class StartupLogic {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    Widget getLandingPage(BuildContext ctx) {
        return StreamBuilder<User>(
            stream: _auth.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (BuildContext ctx, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return HomePageScreen();
              }
    
              return WelcomeScreen();
            });
      } 
    }
```

And in main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  ...

  home: StartupLogic().getLandingPage(context),
```